# Unity Facebook SDK on Android login error

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

Unity 4.3.0f4
Facebook SDK 4.3.6 and 5.0.3 too

- I've downloaded the SDK and imported to a clean project.
- I've created a new Facebook app.
- I've configured the Facebook Edit Settings file with the correct app
  id.
- Copy/Pasted the Android info in Android platform of Facebook app
  configuration tab.

I'm sure everything all OK, but when I try to log into my table with example scene after filling in the email and password, the app shows a pop-up saying "The developers have not set properly this app" and if you close this message in log window you can read "login cancelled by player".

I don't understand why I'm having issues.

Answer (score 0):

You must go to app setting on Facebook and add an Android platform, put your key hash, package name,.. to the platform app setting for register this platform with Facebook.Hope it work. I hate this FB Unity SDK, it has many bug and less support documentation